# how to use xterm in remote system using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAME=KRUNAL
IP=10.61.162.241
ssh -1  ${USERNAME} ${IP} bash << 'EOF'
   xterm -e ./a.out
EOF
```

**Any alternative that i can use with similar use as xterm**

This is not working . Mainly my concerned to run the ./a.out file and i have to check that my application when crashed (MAINLY I HAVE TO BE READY FOR HALT OR CRASH OR STOP) . If it crashed than i will get alert or any information that this /.a.out stopped working .All this things done in remote system and i want to maintain from my system .. So do you have any better idea ??

Comment: `ssh -Y -1 ${USERNAME} ${IP} xterm` should do it (`-Y` enables trusted X11 forwarding, and you need X11 forwarding for xterm to work).

Comment: that's working thanks